# WM_PAINT doesn't show up after painting

Tags: c, windows, api, bitmap, paint

So i'm painting a bitmap, heres my code:

```
hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);

SelectObject(hdcMem, g_hBitmap);
GetObject(g_hBitmap, sizeof(bm), &bm);

BitBlt(hdc, 196 - (bm.bmWidth/2), 90, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

DeleteDC(hdcMem);
```

Sometimes, when I paint it with this code, the bitmap is not displayed. Although if i minimize/unminimize the window, the bitmap is displayed. I'm pretty sure there's no problems with my code so is there something else I should be doing?

***EDIT***:
Turns out it's not just bitmaps, if I draw text with `TextOut` sometimes it's not displayed until its minimized/unminimized. I don't think minimizing/unminimizing sends another `WM_PAINT` message, so I don't think that when i do that it's causing it to be repainted correctly.

Oh and the rest of the controls get painted normally, just the stuff inside WM_PAINT isn't painted.

**UPDATE**
Here's the code thats causing the problems, it works 98% of the time too.

```
// This is a global variable
bool GlobalVar = false;

// This is a different thread started with _beginthread
void ThreadExample()
{
    GlobalVar = true;
    InvalidateRect(hMainWnd, NULL, TRUE);
    _endthread();
}

case WM_PAINT:
    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

    if (GlobalVar == true)
    {
        SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);
        SetTextColor(hdc, 0x0000ff);

        OrigFont = SelectObject(hdc, g_hLargeFont);

        GetTextExtentPoint32(hdc, ErrorMsg, lstrlen(ErrorMsg), &sz);
        TextOut(hdc, 196 - (sz.cx/2), 100, ErrorMsg, lstrlen(ErrorMsg));

        SelectObject(hdc, OrigFont);
    }

    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    break;
```

***EDIT2:***
Another important detail could be, in my actual application, this code is inside a `if` statement that checks a global variable, and paints if its true. And this variable is set from a different thread, and after the variable is set I call `InvalidateRect(hMainWnd, NULL, TRUE);`
Updated my example code to represent this.

Comment: Please can you show us where this code is. I'm hoping it is inside a WM_PAINT handler and that hdc came from BeginPaint.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, it's inside `WM_PAINT`, and the hdc did come from BeginPAint.

Comment: Your edit doesn't help. A minimal reproduction would.

Comment: You forgot to mention the threads!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Didn't think it made a difference since `GlobalVar` is set before `InvalidateRect` is called.

Comment: You are calling `InvalidateRect` from a different thread? That's a no-no right there. Windows have thread affinity. Try your program without the threads and get rid of the global var. If it still misbehaves then come back with a completely reproducible simple example.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Well if I update something that needs to be updated on the GUI in a thread, do you have a better method then calling `InvalidateRect` from the thread?

Comment: Windows have thread affinity. Any procedure that receives a window handle must be called from the thread that created the window. Those are the rules of the game. So you need to post a user-defined message to the main window handle so that it can call `InvalidateRect`. This kind of stuff is hard. Why not use a framework?

Comment: Oh, and the lack of synchronisation on `GlobalVar` cannot be good either.

Comment: Alright I think I figured everything out. @DavidHeffernan thanks for your help, I wish I could accept your comments as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is immediately not good with this code snippet (you actually should rather have posted more details) is that you delete temporary DC with your global bitmap handle still selected into it. You need to do `SelectObject` once again to unselect your bitmap.

You normally do it like this:

```
HGDIOBJ hPreviousBitmap = SelectObject(hdcMem, g_hBitmap);
// ...
SelectObject(hdcMem, hPreviousBitmap);
```

Also, error checking never hurts. Possibly one of the API calls fail and it's important which one exactly as it sheds more light on the issue.